# Defining subcommands that take arguments in bash

Tags: linux, bash

So i want to make a "program" that facilitates commands like the yum commands and anothers... when the program is finished i want put it in /usr/bin with the name "dafs"

i tested with this example which the filename is dafs

```
#!/bin/bash

$1 $2 $3

function yum {
    function maintenance {
        yum -y update
        yum -y upgrade
        yum clean all
    }

    function download {
        yum -y install --downloadonly $3
    }

}
```

but when i run `./dafs yum maintenance` or `./dafs yum download http` it don't work i guess because the syntax is incorrect..

So, how can i pass arguments to functions or sub functions, like the example above?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that "sub functions" are a thing that exist?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So functions inside other functions doesn't exists?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva, you can define functions from within other functions, but they're still just regular functions, not "sub functions", and they live inside the main namespace (they aren't scoped to within the function that defines them). There's no special subcommand magic built in to automatically invoke them the way you're doing it here; you need to write that magic yourself if you want it.

Comment: Also, the `function` keyword is a bashism -- it makes your functions incompatible with more strictly POSIX-compliant shells, but has no other value.

Comment: Also, functions need to be defined **before** they're used, hence, putting the definitions at the top of the file and the launcher assembling those definitions into an invocation at the bottom.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A best-practice way to define subcommands is with a prefixed namespace, and a "launcher" function. This is how `git` does it, for instance (using `git-foo` and `git-bar` commands for `git foo` and `git bar`).

Here, I'm using double-underscores rather than a single dash as the separator, as underscores (unlike dashes) are defined as valid within function names by the POSIX sh standard.

```
yum__maintenance() {
  command yum -y update
  command yum -y upgrade
  command yum clean all
}

yum__download() {
  command yum -y install --downloadonly "$@"
}

yum() {
  local cmdname=$1; shift
  if type "yum__$cmdname" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    "yum__$cmdname" "$@"
  else
    command yum "$cmdname" "$@" # call the **real** yum command
  fi
}

# if the functions above are sourced into an interactive interpreter, the user can
# just call "yum download" or "yum maintenance" with no further code needed.

# if invoked as a script rather than sourced, call function named on argv via the below;
# note that this must be the first operation other than a function definition
# for $_ to successfully distinguish between sourcing and invocation:
[[ $_ != $0 ]] && return

# make sure we actually *did* get passed a valid function name
if declare -f "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  # invoke that function, passing arguments through
  "$@" # same as "$1" "$2" "$3" ... for full argument list
else
  echo "Function $1 not recognized" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

---

Items of note:

- `"$@"` expands to the full list of arguments passed to the current item in scope, preserving argument boundaries and avoiding glob expansion (unlike `$*` and unquoted `$@`).
- `shift` pops the first argument (`$1`) off the front of the list, leaving the new value of `"$@"` one shorter than the old list.
- The `command` builtin causes the real `yum` command to be called, rather than simply recursing into the `yum` function again, when no subcommand exists.
- `declare -f funcname` returns true (and prints that function's definition) if really passed a function. `type`, by contrast, returns true if passed *any* kind of runnable command. Thus, using `type "yum__$cmdname"` allows `yum__foo` to be defined as an external script or any other type of command, not just a function, whereas the `declare -f "$1"` done later allows only functions to be run.

---

A final thing to consider, if you don't intend to support being sourced, would be leaving out the `yum` function, but expanding your launcher to recognize subcommands itself:

```
if declare -f "${1}__$2" >/dev/null; then
  func="${1}__$2"
  shift; shift    # pop $1 and $2 off the argument list
  "$func" "$@"    # invoke our named function w/ all remaining arguments
elif declare -f "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  "$@"
else
  echo "Neither function $1 nor subcommand ${1}__$2 recognized" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

In this case, a subcommand named by the first two arguments is always searched for, followed by a function named by the first argument only.

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva, I don't follow pastebin.com links. Try looking at the site without an adblocker, and you'll understand why -- anyone who tries that hard to monetize isn't to be trusted not to host malware if they get paid the right amount. Consider https://gist.github.com/, or http://ix.io/.

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva, ...because nothing *actually is invoking* those functions, if that's all the code you define. And, for that matter, until it's called, `yum` is the only function that's defined at all; it only defines `download` and `install` functions **when it's invoked** (and, again, they're functions named `download` or `install`, not "subfunctions" `yum download` or `yum install`; as I said in a comment on the question; there is no such thing as a subfunction).

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva, ...so, your `yum` function defines two more functions, but it doesn't actually **call** them. If you wanted to be sloppy, after the definitions you could put `"$@"` inside the `yum` function, but that would be very, **very** sloppy (as in, full of security bugs; it would make giving someone permission to run `sudo dafs` be equivalent to full unrestricted `sudo`). The extra code in my answer is a bunch of extra code, but it serves a useful purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
yum() {
    if [ "$1" = "maintenance" ]; then
        command yum -y update
        command yum -y upgrade
        command yum clean all
    elif [ "$1" = "download" ]; then
        command yum -y install --downloadonly "$2"
    else
       echo "Invalid arg..."
    fi

}

if [ "$1" = "yum" ];then
    shift
    yum "$@"
fi
```

Now you can do `./dafs yum maintenance` or `./dafs yum download http` with it.

Comment: The `x$1` idiom is ancient -- that hasn't been needed since Bourne shell (not 1990s POSIX sh, but 1970s Bourne), so long as you don't use more than three-argument tests.

Comment: That said, this does do what it says; I prefer the more flexible approach since that way subcommands can be written in non-shell languages if one prefers (as is done with `git`, for instance).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : I use that idiom to remind me that I am using `sh`, and also it guards against unintentional unquoted (single word) strings that might be empty for some reason.

Comment: (In the >3-argument test case, ie. when using `-o` or `-a` to combine tests, grouping operators become valid in arbitrary positions, and the total length of the command line is no longer sufficient to distinguish whether a unary or binary operator is in use -- but for `[ "$foo" = "$bar" ]`, the parsing is unambiguous).

Comment: If you have unquoted expansions, you have bigger problems.

Comment: What bugs? There **are** no bugs in any POSIX-compliant `sh` (including `dash`, `ash`, etc) that are fixed by using `"x$foo"` over `"$foo"` in tests, unless you're using features that the POSIX standard has explicitly marked obsolescent.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : I meant, `x$foo` over `$foo` i.e when you write them unquoted unintentionally or mistakenly. But anyway, this is pointless..